# flutter only top shadow to the container

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Flutter need a top shadow, top left and top right shadow line to the  half of the container. I have tried with below code .

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
          child: ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
            child: Container(
              height: 500.0,
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 6.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(30.0)),
                color: Colors.blue,
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    offset: Offset(0.0, 1.0), //(x,y)
                    blurRadius: 5.0,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Required out put in the below image
[image]

Comment: Can you include what you've tried so far?

Comment: i have added the code please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just added one container inside another container and put a gradient beginning and ending to top container

```
    Container(
             width: 320,
              height: 620,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                      begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                      end: Alignment.center,
                      colors: [
                        Colors.green.shade800,
                        Colors.white,
                        Colors.white,
  
                      ])), child: Container(
              width: 310,
              height: 610,
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: const Text('text'),
            ) )
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Community go away bot this answer is fine